# How can i save a lot of images with plt.savefigure() in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mplot3d

i wrote the next code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd 
import pylab as pl 


files = ["xyz_01.txt", "xyz_02.txt", "xyz_03.txt", "xyz_04.txt", "xyz_05.txt", "xyz_06.txt", "xyz_07.txt", "xyz_08.txt", "xyz_09.txt", "xyz_10.txt","xyz_11.txt","xyz_12.txt","xyz_13.txt","xyz_14.txt","xyz_15.txt","xyz_16.txt","xyz_17.txt","xyz_18.txt","xyz_19.txt","xyz_20.txt","xyz_21.txt","xyz_22.txt","xyz_23.txt","xyz_24.txt","xyz_25.txt","xyz_26.txt","xyz_27.txt","xyz_28.txt","xyz_29.txt","xyz_30.txt","xyz_31.txt","xyz_32.txt","xyz_33.txt","xyz_34.txt","xyz_35.txt","xyz_36.txt","xyz_37.txt","xyz_38.txt","xyz_39.txt","xyz_40.txt","xyz_41.txt","xyz_42.txt","xyz_43.txt","xyz_44.txt","xyz_45.txt","xyz_46.txt","xyz_47.txt","xyz_48.txt","xyz_49.txt",]
TB=1
for i in files:
 data=pd.read_csv(i,delim_whitespace=True ,names = ['x', 'y', 'z'])
 T=TB*0.0994
 TB = TB+1 
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
 x=data.iloc[:,0]
 y=data.iloc[:,1]
 z=data.iloc[:,2]
 plt.xlabel("EJE X")
 plt.ylabel("EJE Y")
 pl.plot(x, y, color="blue", linewidth=0, label=str(T))
 pl.legend(loc='upper center',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.95))

 zLabel = ax1.set_zlabel("EJE Z")
 plt.title("Posición de N partículas en el tiempo[Myr]")
 ax1.scatter(x, y, z, c='b', marker='o')
 plt.savefig()
 plt.show()}
```

This code create for each element in the list denominated files a graph.
Know i need save every graph with plt.savefig() but i don't know how can i automatically assign a different name for each file. if you can help me i will be deeply grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of some rule how to convert each file name to 'png' extension or something of this kind. I face a similar problem where I need to change a file extension many times and the most common solution I use is recipes of `os` library for file name manipulation. Your case is quite easy (as long as you don't have complicated file names that consists of multiple points), this is how I do it using `os` in general:

```
import os
file = 'this_is.complicated.txt'
name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
# name is 'this_is.complicated' now
# extension is '.txt' now
```

and if we need to construct a new file name, I replace extension like this:

```
new_file = name + '.png'
# new_file is 'this_is.complicated.png' now
```

Of course, you feed this new name to `savefig` method

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list consists of your file name. Or simply put something like `'img'+i+'.jpg'` and do a recursion.

```
plt.savefig(i[:-4]+'.png')
```

if you want to name your image according to the file. `i[:-4]` is to remove the last 4 characters of `i` so it will remove `.txt` from your file name. This solution  only works with 3 character extension. For general file name, you could use

```
filename, extension = os.path.splitext(i)
```

to split the file name from its extension